# Django: Cant create form

Tags: python, html, django, web

I believe the issue has to do with the views.py when trying to save, as after i click submit it doesnt redirect me to the home page.

Here are the relevant files:

urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('Auditor/', views.Auditor, name='Auditor'),
    path('Auditor/<str:pk>/', views.auditFormPage, name='AuditForm'),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='Register'),
    path('Login/', views.loginPage, name='Login'),
    

]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

views.py:

```
    def auditFormPage(request, pk):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login='nicobari')
    data= datas.objects.get(Task_ID=pk)
    
    context = {
    "items": model,
    "data": data
}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = auditForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Data Updated')
        else:
            messages.success(request,'Data Updated')
    else:
        messages.success(request,'Data Updated')
```

Comment: Registration completing but not redirecting? is it true?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not doing either, as soon as I click on <input type="submit" value="submit"> it refreshes the page but all the data gets refreshed to how it was and no changes made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a friend that fixed it for me by creating the following form:

```
class auditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = datas
        fields = '__all__'
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(auditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].disabled = True # Makes the field un-editable
        self.fields['associate_resolve_date'].disabled = True
        self.fields['QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action'].widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'height: 100px'}) #Sets the size of the widget
        for field in self.fields:
            print(field)
            self.fields[field].required = False
            if field != "qs_login" and field != "Status" and field != "associate_resolve_date" and field != "QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action":
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
```

So for some reason this type of form managed to do the trick, only part i didnt understand was this:

```
for field in self.fields:
                print(field)
                self.fields[field].required = False
                if field != "qs_login" and field != "Status" and field != "associate_resolve_date" and field != "QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action":
                    self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = "form-control"
```

I hope this is somewhat useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

my blog project update method

```
def update(request, slug):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    raise Http404()

blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
form = BlogForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=blog)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, "Blog Updated")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(blog.get_absolute_url())

context = {
    "title": "Blog",
    "form": form
}
return render(request, 'blog/create.html', context)
```

i hope will guide you
[django blog project](https://github.com/mstgnz/blog/blob/30adedfb6c8a21f4ae47b33682b144e669a2a7e3/django/app/views.py#L57)

Comment: This was very helpful but still wont update my page!!!! I dont know whyyyyy

Comment: Are you sure you're using a model form?